# SQL Locking causing timeouts

Tags: sql-server, ado.net, locking, transactionscope, msdtc

We have a long running transaction  (with nested trans), it runs for about 2min. In this time it does a heap of insert, update and selects.  At the same time users still need to be able to use the system.  Some of the tables used are the same as the ones in the batch program.

In the below profiler trace I am getting a block from an unrelated table.  The interesting thing is, the query that is blocking my transaction, the table is not used by the second task.

Here is the profiler output, the blocked process (CustomerOrderEntry) is the quick one while the blocking process is the longer running one.

We are using MSDTC with MS SQL Server and ADO.Net

```
<blocked-process-report monitorLoop="546369">
 <blocked-process>
  <process id="process9fbc51c28" taskpriority="0" logused="10464" waitresource="PAGE: 40:1:182902 " waittime="20839" ownerId="232311233" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2015-05-14T11:52:46.997" XDES="0x12838563b0" lockMode="S" schedulerid="1" kpid="7508" status="suspended" spid="118" sbid="2" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="1" lastbatchstarted="2015-05-14T11:52:47.023" lastbatchcompleted="2015-05-14T11:52:47.023" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.023" clientapp="CustomerOrderEntry.exe" hostname="QIT-TS" hostpid="116616" loginname="QIT\tgower.admin" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="232311233" currentdb="40" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
   <executionStack>
    <frame line="1" stmtstart="52" stmtend="512" sqlhandle="0x02000000946ebc1dc9d4bf7eefd3826e6a744d9b92931d1a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"/>
    <frame line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"/>
   </executionStack>
   <inputbuf>
(@OrderNumber varchar(20))SELECT        Id, OrderNumber, Line, Equipment, Site, Quantity, EngineHours, GPSLongitude, GPSLatitude, OffRoad, Route, Eta, Etd
FROM            CustomerOrderEquipment
WHERE        (OrderNumber = @OrderNumber)
ORDER BY Equipment   </inputbuf>
  </process>
 </blocked-process>
 <blocking-process>
  <process status="suspended" waitresource="40:1:2670699" waittime="49" spid="95" sbid="2" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2015-05-14T11:53:07.817" lastbatchcompleted="2015-05-14T11:53:07.817" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.817" clientapp="EzyserveImport.exe" hostname="QIT-TS" hostpid="25480" loginname="QIT\tgower.admin" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="232308068" currentdb="40" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
   <executionStack>
    <frame line="1" stmtstart="1050" stmtend="2498" sqlhandle="0x0200000050f50e11ba633c312db084db39d3e5c7ff5b8a2d0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"/>
    <frame line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"/>
   </executionStack>
   <inputbuf>
(@Id uniqueidentifier,@Account varchar(12),@Date datetime,@Details varchar(39),@Amount decimal(18,2),@Quantity decimal(18,4),@Source int,@PostingBatch uniqueidentifier,@BASPosition varchar(3),@BASPosted bit,@BASPostedPeriodDate date,@Site int,@Financed bit,@FinancedDate date,@FinancedBatch varchar(8000),@BankRecReference varchar(8000),@BankRecType int,@BankRecPayMedium varchar(8000),@ExcludeFromFinancing bit,@Notes varchar(8000),@Reconciled bit,@ReconciledDate datetime,@FuelSubsidyClaimed bit,@FuelSubsidyClaimDate date)INSERT INTO [LedgerTransactions] ([Id], [Account], [Date], [Details], [Amount], [Quantity], [Source], [PostingBatch], [BASPosition], [BASPosted], [BASPostedPeriodDate], [Site], [Financed], [FinancedDate], [FinancedBatch], [BankRecReference], [BankRecType], [BankRecPayMedium], [ExcludeFromFinancing], [Notes], [Reconciled], [ReconciledDate], [FuelSubsidyClaimed], [FuelSubsidyClaimDate]) VALUES (@Id, @Account, @Date, @Details, @Amount, @Quantity, @Source, @PostingBatch, @BASPosition, @BASPosted,    </inputbuf>
  </process>
 </blocking-process>
</blocked-process-report>
```

Comment: What Isolation Level are you using?

For detecting deadlocks, check out this article:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178104%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

By the sound of it, breaking up this massive transaction into more manageable chunks would be an option. use a cursor or while loop to update/insert/select 1000 parameters at a time and run that in one transaction. this way other transactions can read the data between the breaks. This of course assumes that it is not imperative that all of these updates are read together. 
another option is to change the isolation level that you are using for this query. depending on what kind of data concurrency you need.

(by 1000 parameters I mean if one column is being updated then 1000 rows per transaction, if two columns are being updated then 500 rows per transaction. for most systems 1000 parameters is the "sweet spot" for speed.)